# ¿Como puedo eliminar la publicidad de un video embed?

Tags: php, html

que tal. Hay un hosting de video el cual se llama VOE brinda altas velocidades de reproducción y me interesa usarlo, el problema es que no hay ninguna opción para eliminar la publicidad, ni siquiera pagando.

Me pregunto si se podría eliminar la publicidad del video embed desde la incrustación en html, haciendo con algún script php

Este es el codigo, solamente tiene dos ventanas emergentes cuando inicia el video

```
<iframe src="https://voe.sx/e/dfzsidzoswxz" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Y que fue lo que intentaste? php es un lenguaje de servidor, que esperabas hacer con lo que recibis? parcearlo en un servidor y volver a mandarlo? como un proxy?

Comment: Si el servicio de VOE incluye publicidad es porque así lo han decidido y porque seguramente la necesiten para ofrecerlo gratis. Si no quieres que salga y ellos no disponen de esa opción, deberías buscar otro proveedor que sí te ofrezca esa posibilidad.